# How to create a user really without group in centos 7?

Tags: centos, centos7, useradd

Per [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/950516/is-there-any-security-issue-when-i-set-apache-as-the-only-owner-of-websites-fi),I decide to create dummy user to be the owner of website files.

Centos 7 offer default group ID 100 when I run `useradd -u 508 -M -N -s /sbin/nologin dummyuser1`.
I want to provide as little as possible privilege to the `dummyuser1`,then I don't want `dummyuser1` has group.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `-N` option. You need to create a private user group exclusively for this user.

All users must have a group. If you don't want the user to be in any other groups, then the user should be in its own group. By default a group with the same name as the user is created, and that group has the same name as the user.

Comment: Even I will not provide any permission to `dummyuser1`,such as `----r----- 1 dummyuser apache 1757 Jun 3 2018 index.php`, waste a dummy group for this dummyuser?

Comment: It is not a waste. It is a necessity.